# How to write question in the Future , about planning

Tags: questions

I want to ask if something is planned in the future.
What is the right way and why?
 1. When version 3.8 is planne**d** to be release**d** 
 or
 2. When version 3.8 is planne to be release**d**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's `planned` and `planning,` not `planed` and `planing.` The latter are inflected forms of the verb "to plane," meaning to scrape bits off something with a special woodworking tool until it's flat like a mathematical plane. The double consonants in `planned` and `planning` keep the preceding vowel short, like in "plan," instead of long, like in "plane."

---

Second, questions take the form of a statement with the subject and auxiliary verb in reverse order. Let's start with a statement.

> Version 3.8 is planned.

Now let's make it a question.

> Is version 3.8 planned?

Notice this isn't "Is planned version 3.8?" That's because you don't include the main verb, "plan," in the inversion. You only include the auxiliary verb, "is."

To ask "when," it becomes

> When is version 3.8 planned?

---

Finally, I think you're right; the structure of the past tense of the verb phrase "to plan to release" is awkward and confusing. I think the most natural way to ask this is

> When is the release of version 3.8 planned?

Comment: FYI I corrected the spelling, which impacts your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a native US English speaker, here are some ways I might ask this question:

> When is version 3.8 planned for release?
>
> According to plan, when will version 3.8 be released?
>
> What [or When] is the planned release date for version 3.8?

Comment: Might use "When" is the planned release, not what, but both do work.